# If a sequence of functions $f_n$ converges to $f$ in $L^p$, is it necessary that $f$ itself be in $L^p$?

Tags: integration, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I'm reading Real Analysis for Graduate Students by Richard Bass. One of the exercises is the following:

Prove that if $p$ and $q$ are conjugate exponents, $f_n \to f$ in $L^p(\mu)$ and $g \in L^q(\mu)$, then
$$
\int f_n g d\mu \to \int fg d\mu
$$

The result follows pretty easily if $f$ is in $L^p(\mu)$ and the $f_n$ are eventually in $L^p$, but is this the case? Is it possible for $| |f_n - f| |_p \to 0$ with $f \not\in L^p(\mu)$? I've searched, but no text I've found addresses this issue.

Comment: Let $f_n=f$ for an arbitrary function $f$, then $\|f_n-f\|=0$.

Comment: @egorobik I knew I was missing something silly. Thank you.

Comment: However, when people say 'converges in $X$' it normally means that the what is converging takes values from $X$.

Answer (score 1):

So for some $n$ we must have $\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{p}}< 1$. Now we have $\|f\|_{L^{p}}\leq\|f_{n}-f\|_{L^{p}}+\|f_{n}\|_{L^{p}}<1+\|f_{n}\|_{L^{p}}<\infty$.

Comment: How do we know $f_n$ is ever in $L^p$ though?

Comment: I did not assume the $f_n \in L^p$, only $| | f_n  - f| | \to 0$.

Comment: How do you interpret $f_n\rightarrow f$ in $L^p$?

Comment: Sorry I should have stated that. Richard Bass defines it as $| | f_n  - f| |_p \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$. He puts no assumptions on $f$ nor the sequence. Only that the $p$-norm of their difference tends to $0$.

Comment: Then how would one make sense of the existence of $\displaystyle\int f_{n}g$?

Comment: Good point. How do YOU interpret $f_n \to f$ in $L^p$?

Comment: Normally all $f_{n}$ and $f$ are in $L^{p}$.

Comment: @user284331 There is a difference between the statements $\|f_n-f\|_p \to 0$ and $f_n \to f$ in $L^{p}$. The first one makes sense even if the functions do not belong to $L^{p}$ but the second one does not make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It is against conventions to say that $f_n \to f$ in $L^{p}$ if $\|f_n-f\|_p \to 0$ without $f_n$ and $f$ belonging to $L^{p}$. In any topological space we talk about convergence in the space only for  elements of that space.

If it is assumed that $\{f_n\} \subset L^{q}$ and $(f_n)$ converges in $L^{q}$ the we can say that there exists $f \in L^{q}$ such that $f_n \to f$ in $L^{q}$. But we  cannot make the statement  without knowing that $f \in L^{q}$